# Is this efflorescence on these brick pillars? And is this a sign of water intrusion into the pillars?

Tags: water, structural, brick

There are brick pillars under a bedroom that overhangs. On the brick pillars are some white stuff that I would assume is efflorescence but the patterns are a little weird to me. If that is what it is then does this mean water is getting into the pillars? And if so will this degrade the pillars over time?
[image]

Comment: Can you get a pic that is a little closer?  What is posted makes it impossible to see any details.  Does the stuff flake off?

Comment: Can't see anything in this tiny photo.  It looks like super blury lichens.

Comment: I'll be back at the house tomorrow so I can get a better picture and see if it flakes. Sorry everyone. This was the only photo I had while there.

Comment: Inspector says it is spalling and likely happened some time ago. I guess I keep an eye on it to see if it worsens as I don't know how water would be intruding here.